# when I try to read from txt file it returns : Cannot read input file

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am trying to write a program that compares 2 files and return if their equal or not.

I can only use the functions: fork, dup, dup2, open, write, exec, read.

When I compile the program on linux gcc, it returns 
**Cannot read input file**

```
shay@shay-Latitude-E6410 ~/workspace/targ1OS $ ./comp.out input.txt input.txt Cannot read input file
```

the code:

```
/*
* This function checks if the files are similar or similar by case    sensitive
 * it gets 2 files, and returns: 3 if identical, 2 if identical but only if not
 * case sensitive or 1 else.
 */
int CheckSimilar(char *path1, char *path2){

//open the files
int fd1 = open(path1, O_RDONLY), fd2 = open(path2, O_RDONLY);
int flag = 1;//this flag is to check for case sensitive
char *firstFile = NULL, *secondFile = NULL;
int readBytes, read2ndFile;

if (fd1 == -1 || fd2 == -1){
    write(2, "Cannot open input file\n", 24);
    return -1;//checks if there is a problem opening the file
}

while (1){

    readBytes = read(fd1, firstFile, 1);
    read2ndFile = read(fd2, secondFile, 1);

    if (readBytes < 0 || read2ndFile < 0){
        write(2, "Cannot read input file\n", 24);
        return -1;
    }//checks if there is a problem reading chars from the file

    if (!readBytes || !read2ndFile)
        break;

    if (*firstFile == *secondFile)
        continue;//the chars are equal
    //checks if it's an abc char
    else if ((*firstFile > 64 && *firstFile < 91) ||
            (*firstFile > 96 && *firstFile < 123)){
        // checks for not case sensitive
        if ((*firstFile - *secondFile) == 22 ||
                (*firstFile - *secondFile) == -22)
            flag = 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}

close(fd1);
close(fd2);

if (readBytes != read2ndFile)
    return 1;
if (flag)
    return 2;
return 3;
}
```

Comment: Post your code could be a good starting point. BTW try `./comp.out ./input.txt ./input.txt`

Comment: .. and close your descriptors.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but for efficiency reasons you shouldn't read the files byte per byte but you should read at least 1Kb at a time.

Comment: If `read` returns -1, then `errno` is set and that value will provide more information why the read has failed.

Comment: first: I know the efficiency is bad.
2nd: how can I see the errno value?

Comment: start by printing `path1` and `path2` to make sure they have the values you think they have.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should ask yourself if `write(2, "Cannot read input file\n", 24)` is really a goot idea. (Hint: `"Cannot read input file\n"` has only 23 chars)

Comment: [`perror(path1);`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) may come in handy, btw (or `path2` obviously).

Comment: Please explain. You want me write what exactly?

Comment: I am really new to linux.
please elaborate about the system calls you ask me to write.

Comment: What is there in your file `comp.out`? Is there code in the file `input.txt`?

Comment: input.txt is just a txt file with a few characters - no code

Comment: I see no `Cannot read input file` in your code, so this seems to be a compilation error. What command do you you to compile?

Comment: @jdarthenay I can see `write(2, "Cannot read input file\n", 24);` at line 18.

Comment: @Micheal Oh sorry, I need new glasses...

Comment: ok, I tried your sollutions.
It works if I add ./ before input.txt files.
Is there a solution for not using ./?

Answer (score 2):

Make yourself a better world and ask the system about `errno`, and read the manual about the system calls read(2), open(2),... and errno(3)

(read(2) for example is a manual page address, saying: Manual page "read" in section 2, read `man man` about sections).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
[...]

    char* err = strerror(errno);
    char* errlen = err ? strlen(err): 0;
    char* form = "Cannot read input file since \"%s\".\n"
    if (errlen == 0) {
        form = "Cannot read input file failed with unknown error %d.\n";
        fprintf(stderr, form, errno);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, form, err);
    }
```

As you cannot use fprintf, I leave it for you to write the forms. At least you should print out the `errno` after the failed read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

You declare:

```
 char *firstFile = NULL, *secondFile = NULL;
```

and then you use

```
read(fd1, firstFile, 1);
```

when `firstFile` is `NULL`, and therefore `read` fails.

Declare `firstFile` and `secondFile` like this:

```
char firstFile[1];
char secondFile[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the file exists in the given path or not